# Understanding purescript-variant

Tags: purescript

Newbie here. I'm trying to understand some of the machinery behind [purescript-variant](https://github.com/natefaubion/purescript-variant). Basically what I mean is how to understand these 2 function: [inj](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/4.0.0/docs/Data.Variant#v:inj) and [on](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/4.0.0/docs/Data.Variant#v:on).

When I look at the type of `inj`, the author makes use of [Cons](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-typelevel-prelude/3.0.0/docs/Type.Row#t:Cons) typeclasses. From my understanding, `Cons` place an assertion that there's a record `r2` that can be made from some other record `r1` by inserting a pair of tag/value. So in a sense:

```
r1 + tag/value = r2
```

And in this case `Variant` is the `r2`.

Citing from the readme:

```
foo :: forall v. Variant (foo :: Int | v)
foo = inj (SProxy :: SProxy "foo") 42

bar :: forall v. Variant (bar :: Boolean | v)
bar = inj (SProxy :: SProxy "bar") true

fooToString :: forall v. Variant (foo :: Int | v) -> String
fooToString = on (SProxy :: SProxy "foo") show (\_ -> "not foo")
```

This is where it gets confusing for me. I can feed the `bar` as an argument to `fooToString` while from the type of `bar` there's no guarantee that it has a tag "foo" even if it's an open type. How is this possible?

Comment: After some more thinking. I guess this is because the type of `fooToString` itself doesn't restrict that the variant has to have a tag of "foo" in it. And also becaue of the open types. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `foo` and `bar` restrict that the variant type has to contain some tag, but they don't prevent other tags from being included in the variant. The concrete types when you apply `fooToString bar` would be:

```
 bar :: Variant (bar :: Boolean, foo :: Int) -- v = (foo :: Int)
 fooToString :: Variant (foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean) -> String -- v = (bar :: Boolean)
```

As you can see, they are perfectly compatible.

---

The internals version of the types would be

```
bar :: forall r1 r2. RowCons "bar" Boolean r1 r2 => Variant r2
fooToString :: forall r1 r2. RowCons "foo" Int r1 r2 => Variant r2 -> String
```

which will specialize to

```
bar :: RowCons "bar" Boolean (foo :: Int) (foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean) => Variant (foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean)
fooToString :: RowCons "foo" Int (bar :: Boolean) (foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean) => Variant (foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean) -> String
```

Where, for `bar`, `r1` is set to/specialized into `(foo :: Int)` and `r2` becomes `(foo :: Int, bar :: Boolean)`. Similarly for `fooToString`.

As you can see, r1 is unused outside of the constraint for both bar and fooToString, which allows them to be chosen freely to satisfy the constraints. It would be be equally valid for the compiler to add even more (unused) variants to the type, but that wouldn't change the result.

---

#### Edit:

Something that is unusual about Pruescript is that not only functions, but also values can be polymorphic. In this case, `bar` is a polymorphic value and `fooToString` is a polymorphic function. This means that the users of both `bar` and `fooToString` are free to choose any type for `v` (or `r1`/`r2`), as long the type contains the required variants.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand the reasoning behind it until the "specialize" part, from what I've understand `bar` contains the "bar" tag and `n` other tags but it might or might not contains the "foo" tag, while `fooToString` explicitly says that it needs variant with at least a "foo" tag in it. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @autumn322 The key information here is that bar is polymorphic. It can take many different types. You can view it as a function that takes a type `v` as an argument and returns a value of type `Variant (bar :: Boolean | v)` for that specific `v`.